# can't access mediawiki site with ssl database user

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I just added a remote database to my media wiki setup. I can access the database from the command line with a regular database user and using that info in the config the wiki site shows up in a browser and works.

But some of the data is sensitive so I need to add an ssl user to access the database.

If I add an ssl user to the db, I can also access it from the command line of the web server no problem:

```
[root@ops:~] #mysql -uadmin_ssl -p -h db.example.com -e "SHOW DATABASES"
Enter password:
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| certs              |
| information_schema |
| jfwiki             |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

But with the ssl user in place in LocalSettings.php, I'm getting this response from the browser:

```
Sorry! This site is experiencing technical difficulties.

Try waiting a few minutes and reloading.

(Cannot access the database: Access denied for user 'admin_ssl'@'ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES) (db.example.com))

You can try searching via Google in the meantime.
Note that their indexes of our content may be out of date.

JF Wiki  WWW
```

This is what the grant for the user looks like in the database:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for  'admin_ssl'@'ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for admin_ssl@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com                                                                                                        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin_ssl'@'ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*somePasswordHash' REQUIRE SSL |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I was just wondering what I'd need to do to make this work!! All suggestions welcomed.

Comment: At what server is your wiki running? The **ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com** or another machine?

Comment: Hi Norbert,

Nope.. That's odd. That ec2 address if for my first load balancer. I didn't mention that the database was a load balanced entitiy because I wasn't thinking it was important. But I guess it is!

Comment: However when I log into the load balancer mentioned in the error, I can log into the database using the admin_ssl credentials from the command line.

Cheers

Comment: If I bypass the load balancer and try to access the 1st datbase directly, I get this error:

(Cannot access the database: Access denied for user 'admin_ssl'@'ops.example.com' (using password: YES) (xx.xx.xx.xx))

The 'x'd out IP in the error is the IP of the 1st database. I notice that if I perform the grant that the error complains about not being able to access the db, and flush privileges the error remains>

I think that the problem is some interraction with how media wiki handles SSL. I don't think it's a grant problem otherwise I wouldn't be able to access the DB from the command line.

Comment: It depends on the load balancing method: If you login to the load balancer (the host system) and then mysql: You do not use the load balancer software, just the host + OS. If the load balanced really redirects the session to the database, then the database sees your front end host direct, and a grant is needed: See what happens when you add the grant.

Comment: I have a grant that allows the web server to log into the database directly (without the load balancer). And I can log into the DB directly from the web server. I'm using round robin as the lb algorithm. I found this article:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBssl

And now my connect string looks like this:
## Database settings
$wgLBFactoryConf['class'] = 'LBFactorySimple';
$wgDBservers = '';
$wgDBtype = "mysql";
$wgDBserver = "db.example.com";
$wgDBssl    =  "db.jokefire.com";
$wgDBname = "jfwiki";
$wgDBuser = "admini_ssl";
$wgDBpassword = "secret";

Comment: But when I refresh the page I see the same error
(Cannot access the database: Access denied for user 'admini_ssl'@'ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES) (db.example.com))

That error points to the load balancer for some reason. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any fundamental difference between connecting via the command line MySQL client from your webserver and using MediaWiki; if one works and the other does not, you probably configured them differently. At a guess, the command line client uses ssl because it is enabled in `my.cnf`, but you did not set [`$wgDBssl`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBssl) or an equivalent setting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I realize you are correct that there is no fundamental difference in connecting from the mysql client on the command line to the db and using mediawiki.

I did have ssl configured for the client in my.cnf on the web server I was testing from:

```
[client]
ssl-ca=/opt/mysql/ca.crt
ssl-cert=/opt/mysql/ops.example.com.crt
ssl-key=/opt/mysql/ops.example.com.key
```

That's why I was able to connect from the web server to the DB using SSL.

The problem I found was that I didn't know and wasn't aware of the $wgDBssl setting.

I read about that here:

[Mediawiki $wgDBssl](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBssl)

These were the settings in LocalSettings.php that got this working for me:

```
## Database settings
$wgLBFactoryConf['class'] = 'LBFactorySimple';
$wgDBservers = '';
$wgDBtype = "mysql";
$wgDBserver = "db.example.com";
$wgDBssl    =  1;
$wgDBname = "jfwiki";
$wgDBuser = "admin_ssl";
$wgDBpassword = "secret";
```

I can now load the wiki page using SSL on the load balanced database VIP. And I have restored all web servers to the load balancing pool. And still the wiki site is working great!

Thanks for your input!
Tim